# Uploadify with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, file-upload

I'm using [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to upload documents to SharePoint library.
It gives me 403 error sometimes and sometimes it works fine. 
I tried to find solution on 403 error but could not find the proper solution. Can anyone suggest me the proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

**403: Forbidden (Access Denied)**

Can you make sure in the cases it works fine from which user you are logged in, maybe you need to give permissions to the users in SharePoint Library..